# Why am I getting an error node:internal/errors:477 when i implement Nodemailer to the contact form?

Tags: node.js, recaptcha, nodemailer

One of the spam bot companies found my clients website so they bombarded it with 1500 emails from her contact form at a time 2ce a day. i used recaptcha but I am not sure why its giving me an error on the submission side. backend. i started with nodemailer and then the video on recaptcha but it did not help.someone told me I'm implemented. i really need a solutin

this is how my code looks at the moment:

```
 const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
 const express = require('express')
 const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch')
 const app = express()

 app.use(express.static('public'))

 app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
// const name = req.body.name

let output = `
            <p>You have a new Inquiry</p>
            <h3>Contact Details</h3>
            <ul>  
            <li><strong>Solution Inquiry: </strong> ${req.body.subject}</li>
            <li><strong>Name: </strong> ${req.body.name}</li>
            <li><strong>Surname: </strong> ${req.body.surname}</li>
            <li><strong>Email: </strong> ${req.body.email}</li>
            <li><strong>Phone: </strong> ${req.body.phone}</li>
            </ul>
            <h3>Message</h3>
            <p>${req.body.message}</p>
        `
   // var subject

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
       host: 'youremail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
     user: 'info@youremail.com',
      pass: 'password@01',
   },
    tls: {
     rejectUnauthorized: false,
   },
 })

 let mailOptions = {
   from: 'Contact form <info@youremail.com>', // sender address
   to: 'info@youremail.com', // list of receivers'
   subject: `${req.body.subject} Contact Inquiry`, // Subject line
   text: 'Contact Request ', // plain text body
   html: output, // html body
 }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error)
    }
   console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId)
   console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info))
 })
 res.redirect('contact.html')
 const response_key = req.body['g-recaptcha-response']
 const secret_key = '6Lcc8TEiAAAAAHFytJxpFfeNZ_GV-t5vPN3Y7NDG'

 const url = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? 
 secret=${secret_key}&response=${response_key}`

 fetch(url, {
   method: 'post',
 })
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((google_response) => {
     if (google_response.success == true) {
       return res.send({ response: 'Successful' })
   } else {
     return res.send({ response: 'Failed' })
   }
   })
  .catch((error) => {
   // Some error while verify captcha
   return res.json({ error })
   })
    })

    const PORT = 4000
     app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on PORT ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: Would be really useful if you posted the actual (full) error message.